# How can write switch case for value of a prop of a subject in a ts file

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a object like below:

```js
{a:
          auth?.type === '1' || auth?.type === '2' || auth?.type === '3'
            ? {
                reason: // here i want write switch case 
            : undefined,
}
```

how can I write a switch case in this situation ?

Comment: What would the `switch` do? What do you mean *that* code to do, for that matter? (As shown, you have a syntax error.)

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't *(reasonably¹)*, `switch` is a statement, and where you want to put it, only an expression is valid, not a statement.

While you *could* have a deeply-nested set of conditional operators (`? :`) instead, usually, your best bet in this situation is to determine that value before starting your object literal. Deeply-nested sets of conditions are hard to read and hard to debug.

So I'd suggest doing the `switch`, storing the result in a variable, and then using the variable in the object literal. (I'd give an example, but it's not clear what you want the `switch` to do, or what your current code is doing.)

---

¹ *Unreasonably* you could have an inline function you call there with a `switch` in it where you return the value you want. Or more reasonably: define a function you'll reuse that returns the value you want, and call it.